# Libraries for building a backup program in .NET

Tags: windows, software-development, backup, .net, file-synchronization

I'm thinking of building a [backup program that suits my needs](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/27957/backup-software-using-hardlinks-for-deduplication) and since I'm familiar with C#, I'm looking for a few libraries that I'd need to achieve that.

The library or libraries should support

- easy handling of volume shadow copies, since I want to create a copy on the source disk before operating on it

  - creating a copy
  - accessing files in that copy
- support for transactional file system, since I want to write to the destination disk using TxF
- support for long file names, and I mean the maximum of 32000 characters on NTFS, not the usual 255
- prevent the PC from shutting down or restarting (like the typical Windows updates being installed over night)

The libraries must

- allow commercial use

  - open source preferred
  - not require me to provide the source
  - BSD or MIT license preferred
- support .NET 4.5
- support 64 bit

My budget in total is ~200 € (220 USD).